# I get "access denied" when I submit a job in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I upload a video in one asp.net page, save the asset in a session variable, and then in another asp.net page, I use that asset to hopefully encode the video (using azure media services calls).  The I get an error when I submit the encoding job (with job.submit).  It says that access is denied, and the type of exception is: system.security.cryptography.cryptographicException.

I'm wondering if the reason is that I create a context in the new page?

Here is the code from page #1:

```
 Dim mediaServicesAccountName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accountname")
        Dim mediaServicesAccountKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accountkey")
        Dim mediaCloud As New CloudMediaContext(mediaServicesAccountName, mediaServicesAccountKey)
        Dim assetOptions As New AssetCreationOptions()

        asset = mediaCloud.Assets.Create(Filename, assetOptions)
        Session("azureasset") = asset
        Dim assetFile As IAssetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(Filename)       
                Session("assetFile") = assetFile
```

Here is the code from page #2:
        Sub Page_Load
        Dim asset As IAsset
        asset = CType(Session("azureasset"), IAsset)
        Dim assetname As String
        assetname = asset.Name ' just for debugging

```
    _context = New CloudMediaContext(_accountName, _accountKey)
    CreateEncodingJob(asset)
    End Sub

Private Function CreateEncodingJob(asset As IAsset) As IJob
    Dim job As IJob = _context.Jobs.Create("My encoding job")
          Dim processor As IMediaProcessor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encoder")
    Dim task As ITask = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task", processor, "H264 Broadband 720p", Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration)

    task.InputAssets.Add(asset)
    ' Add an output asset to contain the results of the job. 
    ' This output is specified as AssetCreationOptions.None, which 
    ' means the output asset is not encrypted. 
    task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output asset", AssetCreationOptions.None)

    ' Use the following event handler to check job progress. 
    Dim ev As New EventHandler(AddressOf StateChanged)
    AddHandler job.StateChanged, AddressOf StateChanged
           ' Launch the job.
    job.Submit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to only keep AssetID in your session. Then get the IAsset reference from the CloudMediaContext once you create it. Use a code similar to this (C#):

```
//var assetId = [Get this from Session, not the entire Asset object]
var asset = _context.Assets.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(assetId)).FirstOrDefault();
// no configure the job with this asset..
```

My best bet goes to the fact that indeed you create the CloudMediaContext again, and the reference to the asset is lost. Your new instance of Media Context does not know anything about this asset object you have in your session.